# fetching data using laravel elquent with multiple associated array in one query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I wonder if there is one query can fetch like associated array form `DB` the key is a column in table and values all records that have the same key, like grouping with data using Laravel

```
table city ['name','country','barcode']
```

Example :

```
'egypt'=>[['cairo','egypt','02'],['alex','egypt','02']],
'usa'=>[['washington','usa','56'],['california','usa','56']],
```

--
I try

$data=Citry::groupBy('country')->get();

but it fetch just  first record from every country

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49799753/754119

Comment: please provide some code or example that you want.. if you only provide information like this.. the others can't help you to solve your problem, because we don't know what is your problem

Comment: He has posted this already, flagged for moderation review.

Comment: @Adam That flag will probably be declined because you can flag this post as duplicate and the community will handle this (By voting to close the post as duplicate). You can retract your flag if you wish

Comment: Aren't dupes for those with previously answered questions?

Comment: @Adam Although the help text says that exceptions can be made, especially where the question is essentially exactly the same

Comment: Just fixed the flag, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Adam just don't go too wild ;), questions can have subtle differences

Comment: @alonEitan i delete the past question , this more specific i want to handle that with laravel collection

Comment: @jamesRiady 
ex 
Citry::groupBy('countr')->get();
i want collection fetch 
all cities in each country in city table 
.
note -- there is no table for county just name on column country

Answer (score 1):

You need a controller then put this on your controller

```
$cities = City::all();
foreach($cities as $city)
{ 
    $data[$city->country][] = $city;
}
return response()->json($data);
```

the variable countries will only get the first row data of every each country, because the point is group by country that you only need to get the unique country.
After that I do loop as many as the countries length and show the data of every country

Comment: this good but i want make nasted for loop , with this i can do that 
---
i will display countries and each country display each city in it 
---
like egar loading relation

Comment: let check my answer again

Comment: i solved by make there is relation ship between country table (made new) and city table , i load countries and egar load cities with it , 
so i can make naseted loops one for countries and inside each country their cities

Comment: it's okay.. but if you have solved your problem please share your answer . So the others can solve their problem if they have the same problem with you. But if you try my code and it works as you want, please do tick in my answer.. Because I think you can solve it without make any table.. ^^